# ¿Cómo realizar tests de código de producción(src/main) desde el paquete src/test en Java?

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, maven, test

Tengo un proyecto en Java y Spring boot y estoy realizando mis primeros tests en Java y quería consultar si puedo realizar Tests sobre el código del proyecto que tengo actualmente, pero sin copiar el contenido de **src/main/java** a **/src/test/java**

Por lo que tengo entendido tengo que realizar una copia del código que tengo en **src/main/java** hacia el paquete de los tests y no quiero ir copiando código cada vez que tenga cambios en el código fuente del proyecto 
¿Existe alguna manera de poder *"enlazar"* el contenido del código fuente para realizar las pruebas unitarias?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario copiar nada, tú solo debes crear tus test unitarios para las operaciones que necesites. Por ejemplo si tienes lo siguiente:

```
public class Addeer {

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}


import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class AdderTest {

    Adder adder = new Addeer();

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        int actual = adder.add(5, 10);
        int expected = 15;
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Lo unico que necesitas es algún framework para realizar los test unitarios, el estándar de facto es JUnit, pero como ves no es necesario en ningún caso realizar una copia.

La estructura de la que hablas, `src/main/java` y `src/test/java` son específicas de maven, y basta con ubicar tus fuentes en el primer directorio y los test unitarios en el segundo.

Adicionamente debes agregar la dependencia de JUnit a tu archivo `pom.xml` y listo, ya estás en condiciones de hacer tu test con `mvn test`

Comment: Sólo a través de la terminal puedo ejecutar los tests?

Comment: No, lo puedes hacer con algún IDE también pero en realidad lo que hace el IDE es ejecutar los test por debajo igual a como lo harías tú vía una terminal (windows, linux, macos) y seguramente te los presentará de una forma más atractiva visualmente.

Comment: Perfecto! Cuando tenga resultados te contesto.

Comment: Estimado la idea del sitio es responder preguntas bien formuladas para poder ayudar a la comunidad. No es un sitio de soporte por lo que de aquí en más debes continuar con tus pruebas. Nos alegra que hayas podido encontrar la solución. Si tienes más consultas puedes ir creando nuevas en el portal, sin embargo la idea es que siempre dediques tiempo a investigar antes de realizar la pregunta. Saludos.